# Query Identities with VSTS client libraries

Tags: .net, azure-devops

When I call ReadIdentitiesAsync on an IdentityHttpClient from the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client nuget package:

```
using (var client = new IdentityHttpClient(baseUrl, credentials))
{
    identities = await client.ReadIdentitiesAsync(IdentitySearchFilter.General, "user@company.com");
}
```

This exception is thrown:

> API resource location 28010c54-d0c0-4c89-a5b0-1c9e188b9fb7 is not registered on https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/

Is there another uri I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base url used for the identity api is not the same as for the other apis.

For most clients in the client library, use https://myaccount.visualstudio.com

For the identity client, use https://myaccount.vssps.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 0):

I get the same exception when use it with VSTS, but the code can works correctly with on-premise TFS server.

As an alternative way, you can use the [.NET client libraries](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet) API to get the identity information.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server;

namespace NetAPIID
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://xxx.visualstudio.com";

            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(url));
            ttpc.EnsureAuthenticated();

            IGroupSecurityService igss = ttpc.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();

            Identity id = igss.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.AccountName, "user@company.com", QueryMembership.None);
        }
    }
}
```